# Intellij: how to exclude Scala libraries from Java code completion?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am working on a mixed Java-Scala project in Intellij 13. When autocompleting a class which shares a name with a class in the Scala standard libraries (such as Set, List, Map etc), it seems that IntelliJ defaults to the Scala class. This happens even when working on a Java file, in a folder designated in the Project Folder as a Java source folder.

As an example, this happens constantly when using Java Collections. Trying to autocomplete for example List or Set launches me immediately into the midst of the Scala Collection hierarchy.

Is there any way to tell Intellij to NOT include any Scala libraries at all when autocompleting in a Java file?

Comment: I know Intellij knows how to disable autocomplete and autoimport for certain classes, but it's one setting for both languages. Settings→Editor→AutoImport. In your case, I'd ban `scala.collection`, because usually when you need something from there it's easy enough to type it by hand.